# How to use Matlab data in R?

Tags: r, matlab, import, matrix, export

Well I have a matrix in Matlab, with 4 dimensions. I'd like to export this matrix to use it in R (I want to plot with it). The problem for me is that I don't know how to export a matrix that can be used by R, and also I don't know how to import data in R. Basically, what I've tried to do is to export my matrix in Matlab using `dlmwrite`, and importing it in R using `read.table()`. Unfortunately this isn't working.

Comment: did you look into the `R.matlab` package?   http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html

Comment: In what formats can you export the array from Matlab. If you could include an example of that sort of file I'm sure the combined efforts of the R community on SO can find a way to read it into an R array.

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.pdf should get you on the way of importing data into R.

Answer (score 2):

You can write out any array to binary with fwrite, and read it into R with readBin. In R that will give a vector that you can push into shape with array() or matrix().

Here's a very simple example.

```
a = magic(4)

con = fopen('a.bin', 'w');
fwrite(con, a * 0.01, 'float64')
fclose(con)

a * 0.01
```

ans =

0.1600    0.0200    0.0300    0.1300

0.0500    0.1100    0.1000    0.0800

0.0900    0.0700    0.0600    0.1200

0.0400    0.1400    0.1500    0.0100

Now in R:

```
 matrix(readBin("a.bin", "double", 16), 4)
```

[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]

[1,] 0.16 0.02 0.03 0.13

[2,] 0.05 0.11 0.10 0.08

[3,] 0.09 0.07 0.06 0.12

[4,] 0.04 0.14 0.15 0.01

You could replace "a" with a 4D array, and change the R code to this and it should work just as well:

```
## assume 4 dimensions with particular sizes
dims <- c(10, 5, 2, 3)
a <- array(readBin("a.bin", "double", prod(dims)), dims)
```

Finally, note that this assumes the same byte ordering in Matlab and R. See machineformat in the Matlab fwrite help if your end systems are different.

Comment: I used to do this a lot, I'll try to dig up actual code and explain more.

Comment: But, the R.matlab package is very good for reading .mat files and can easily handle much more varied outputs than this.